# Which Dessert fit a Thai dish?

Tags: dessert, thai-cuisine

I plan to cook a thai dish this weekend and I search for a *dessert* that fits to that. In particular it will be a chicken dish with lemon gras.

*I moved the drink part of the question [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17752/which-drinks-fit-to-a-thai-dish). Sorry for that.*

Comment: This is a poll, not a question. Please re-phrase or it will get closed

Comment: Changed it. Is it ok like that?

Comment: He was referring to the fact that on this site, we only want to have questions with a single correct answer. The problem with your question is that if somebody says "the best Thai dessert is a mango" and another one says "the best Thai dessert is a pineapple", none of the answers is objectively better than the other one. See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask for details.

Comment: I forked the question, sorry for that! I absolutely understand the problem!

Comment: Welcome to the site moonglum. Open ended poll type questions are not a good fit for our site. Questions asked here must have reasonably objective answers.

Answer (score 2):

what about thai iced tea, and sticky rice with the mango?

Comment: This is the standard at my regular Thai restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

Fresh fruit (mango, coconut, pineapple) is always a great dessert, and [Thai iced tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_tea) is a refreshing drink (I actually sometimes drink it instead of having dessert because it's often really sweet.)

Answer (score 0):

For dessert, I've made:

1 can Coconut Milk
4 bananas

Cut the bananas up into 1" chunks.  Add to a pan with the coconut milk and gently cook.  I have a spice called "Sweet Spice" made by Alchemy Spice company that I add to the mixture as well.

Pre-prepare some mugs with vanilla ice cream in the freezer.  Pull the mugs out of the freezer and add some of the banana / coconut milk mixture and serve.

Answer (score 0):

Thai tea is a must but don't forget about pickled lemonade.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanh_mu%E1%BB%91i

柯柏庭.

Comment: Sorry, but I moved that part of the question :(