# Which drinks fit to a Thai Dish?

Tags: drinks, thai-cuisine

I plan to cook a thai dish this weekend and I search for *drinks* to serve along to that. In particular it will be a chicken dish with lemon gras.

*This is forked from another question of mine.*

Comment: Welcome to the site moonglum. Open ended poll type questions are not a good fit for our site. Questions asked here must have reasonably objective answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good Belgian Wit beer would go well with Thai food.   The coriander and citrus in the beer would complement the dish, but a good one will not overpower the food.   The light mouthfeel from a Wit would help cleanse your palate and refresh without filling you up.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're looking for likely alcoholic drinks, but the ever popular Thai Iced Tea is great because the cream in the Thai iced tea cuts the heat from the Thai spices.  So even in that vein, I would suggest creamy drinks.  I know the cultures are not similar, but it seems like white russians would taste great with Thai food.

Here's a link of creamy drinks: http://www.cocktailsonline.tv/cream.html

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across an article that said sweet Sauternes wines were a great match for Thai food. A quick search on Google leads me to believe that this may not be as crazy as it sounds. Here is an example:
http://www.thewinecellarinsider.com/forums_new/showthread.php?46-Sauternes-and-food-pairing-question-from-Chateau-Coutet

In that thread a person says he has had great experiences of pairing Sauternes with Thai food, particularly a 1975 Chateau Rieussec that he had at Lotus of Siam in Vegas.

If you feel adventurous, maybe that is a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Forget wine, forget tea, there is only one answer to this question. Well two really. Your choice of Chang beer or Singer beer in a glass with ice.

Comment: Some choice-- one results in a "Changover", the other has formaldehyde in it.